# Bash remove quotes for String argument

Tags: string, bash, parameters

I need to execute a command in bash that takes a constructed argument. The string argument needs to be passed without quotations. How do I remove the quotes?

This does not work:

```
Tracks='bark.mov'
TrackDir='~/soundtracks/'
TrackPath=$TrackDir$Track
omxplayer -o local $TrackPath
```

This does not work:

```
omxplayer -o local '~/soundtracks/bark.mov'
```

This does work:

```
omxplayer -o local ~/soundtracks/bark.mov
```

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Double quotes also prevent tilde expansion.

Comment: `TrackDir=~/'soundtracks/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilde expansion only works outside of quotes. Get rid of the quotes when defining the variables, but *do* include quotes when expanding them.

```
Tracks=bark.mov
TrackDir=~/soundtracks/
TrackPath=$TrackDir$Track
omxplayer -o local "$TrackPath"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave the `~` unquoted so that the shell can expand it to the user's home directory. Further, it's better practice to add the path separator when you *join* the two, to make it explicit. Having two adjacent `/` in the path doesn't hurt.

```
Tracks=bark.mov
TrackDir=~/soundtracks/
TrackPath=$TrackDir/$Track
omxplayer -o local "$TrackPath"
```